# Finding a particular low-rank subspace via optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

I have two [$n \times k$] matrices $X$ and $Y$, and a symmetric [$m \times m$] matrix $B$.

At a high-level, my goal is to find a low-rank subspace, $A$, in which $X$ and $Y$ are related by the linear mapping $B$. To find $A$, I've come up with the following optimization problem:

$$ \min_{A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}\mbox{, }A^TA = I} \| YA - XAB \|_F^2 $$

where $\|C\|_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} (C_{i,j})^2$ is the Frobenius norm.

I have a couple of questions:

- Is this problem tractable? Any ideas for how I might decompose this somehow into a more convenient form?
- Is this objective convex? (I realize that my domain, the set of rank-m projection matrices, isn't a convex set. But I'm curious to know if the objective function itself is convex.)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It seems that this is very similar to CCA, which, to put it roughly, finds $A$ and $C$ so that $YA \approx XC$. Here, I have the added requirement that $C = AB$, where $B$ is the symmetric matrix above. And I need for $A$ to have orthonormal columns.

Comment: If you don't mind a convex relaxation of the constraints to $\|A^j\|_2 \le t$ for each column $A^j$ of $A$, then your problem can be easily solved via a fast projected-gradient algorithm like FISTA.

Comment: The objective you have written is clearly convex (simple quadratic expression). The constraint is not convex though (quadratic equality)